# MongoDB calculating score from an existing fields and put it in a new collection after aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on Mongodb and I have three collections, let's say `Collection1`, `Collection2` and `Collection3`.

I have to calculate a score from existing fields in `Collection1`, and aggregate it with other fields in `Collection2` and `Collection3`, and finally put this result in a new `Collection4`. For example

**Collection 1:**

```
db.Collection1.find().pretty().limit(2) {
  "_id": ObjectId("5717a5d4578f3f2556f300f2"),
  "Field1": "XXXX",
  "Field2": 0,
  "Field3": 169,
  "Field4": 230,
  "Field5": "...4.67", // This field refer to days in a week
  "Field6": "ZZ",
  "Field7": "LO"
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("17a5d4575f300f278f3f2556"),
  "Field1": "YYYY",
  "Field2": 1,
  "Field3": 260,
  "Field4": 80,
  "Field5": "1.3....", // This field refer to days in a week
  "Field6": "YY",
  "Field7": "PK"
}
```

**Collection2:**

```
db.Collection2.find().pretty().limit(2) {
   "_id": ObjectId("5718e71c6c9678c8cf600068"),
   "Field1": 1,
   "Field2": "XXXX",
   "Field3": "555",
   "Field4": "ABC DEF "
 } {
   "_id": ObjectId("8c8cf65718e71c6c96700069"),
   "Field1": 2,
   "Field2": "YYYY",
   "Field3": "666",
   "Field4": " HTL MPO"

 }
```

**Collection3:**

```
db.Collection3.find().pretty().limit(2) {
  "_id": ObjectId("717a5d45578f3f2556f300f2"),
  "Field1": "ZZ",
  "Field2": "GTH",
  "Field3": "TEST"
}, {
  "_id": ObjectId("17a5d4575f300f278f3f2556"),
  "Field1": "YYYY",
  "Field2": "ZLT",
  "Field3": "TEST2"
}
```

So, I have to do some calculations to my first collection fields just with this formula :

```
Score = C1*C2*C3*C4

C1 = 10 + 0.03*field3
C2 = 1 or 0.03 it depends on field2 if it equals 1 or 0
C3 = 1 or 2 .... or 7, it depends on field5 for example C3 for this document "Field5": "...4.67" should return 3, it means three days per week
C4 = 1 or field4^-0.6 if field2 equals 0 or 1
```

After taking this score I should aggregate it with another fields in `Collection2` and `Collection3` just like this :

```
db.Collection4.findOne() {
  "_id": ObjectId("46f300f255717a5d78f3f255"),
  "Field1": "Collection1.Field1",
  "Field2": "Collection1.Field6",
  "Field3": "Collection1.Field7",
  "Field4": "Collection2.Field4",
  "Field5": "Collection3.Field2",
  "Field6": "Score" // the score that we just calculate c1*c2*c3*c4
}
```

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: In one shot, you can't.  You can only aggregate from a single collection.

Comment: In this case, I may add the calculated score to my Collection 1, can you help me to do it, especially in field5 how can I deal with that string "1.3...." for my calculation